# Envío código ¿Cómo hacer que me imprima las variables declaradas? , es python

Tags: python

```
if__name__=="__main__":
nombre='Juan Carlos'
curso='python'
print("hello world, I'm 
{nombre}. I'm working in 
{curso}")
```

//Cómo imprimir las variables que se declararon ya que al imprimir me sale lo que está entre llaves

Answer (score 1):

Cambia el contenido del print por:

```
print(f"hello world, I'm {nombre}. I'm working in {curso}")
```

O

```
print(f'hello world, I\'m {}. I\'m working in {curso}').format(nombre, curso))
```